# Is it normal for a Kalanchoe to bloom in spring?

Tags: succulents

I have a Kalanchoe in yellow. I left it out too long last fall & almost all of it died but 1 little sprig. Wasn`t sure what to do so I have a tall pitcher oriental style slim neck, the stem just fit in it. have vining plant in main side, it stayed there all winter started putting on leaves then this spring it started blooming. the roots are almost 2" long, I will pot before long. Is this normal for these plants or did I just  get lucky? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add some pictures so we can see what you are dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

Some *Kalenchoe* can be very easy to root from cuttings, particularly *K. blossfeldiana* cultivars. I've even rooted leaves before. Given the poor health of the original plant and small size of the cutting, it may have been stress that induced flowering (many plants will try to set seed whilst they are dying). However, your cutting does sound like it has put on some good root growth. Pot it up in  a free draining medium (straight shop-bought multi-purpose compost tends to become waterlogged) and (though it might seem cruel) cut the flowers off this time to conserve the plants energy for growth. Protect from frost this time!